# Recommendation for simple free CD copier software

Tags: software-rec, burning, cd-burning

I need recommendations for software to make copies of audio CDs for a person who is prone to PEBKAC (Problem Exists Between Keyboard And Chair) errors.

I would personally use ImgBurn or CloneCD, but she wants free (so no CloneCD) and I don't want her to have to deal with .ISOs (ImgBurn). I'd prefer something that isn't a bloated beast like Nero.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What output format do you want?

Comment: @tomwij I believe he wants to burn cd's but I'm just guessing based on what I see in his question.

Comment: Yes, I want CD to CD. I will try the 2 products recommended below, and see which one I will recommend to her. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) is also excellent and, despite its name, it works on all newer versions of Windows ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [InfraRecorder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/infrarecorder/) in the past with great success. It's simple, easy to use, and works on CD's and DVD's.